# How to click on a confirm button inside a modal that's a pop up

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I want to click on the "Confirm" button in the pop up inside a modal. But when I click on the captured webElement

Example:

```
@FindBy(xpath = "//div[@class='modal-footer']//button[text()='Confirm']")
WebElement clickOnConfirmButton;
```

No such element exception error is displayed.

I am attaching the screenshot of the html as well as the webpage on which I am working. 
     [image]

[image]

Note:

1. When I try to find the element using xpath on the console using $x() of the browser, it gets detected. However when I try to execute my code using the same xpath it throws a no such element exception.
2. Warning modal is a modal inside a modal.

Comment: Can you post your code? I have done this several times without problems.

Comment: it would be better when you copy your code, url and other things that can help others solve your problem instead of attaching images.
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: There is either an `iframe` element higher up in the DOM that is not being detected, or you need to invoke a `WebDriverWait` on the element before attempting to locate it -- the `NoSuchElement` exception can be thrown in cases where the page takes too long to load.

Comment: @Vinyasjain77 Are you using _Page Objects_ with _Page Factory_?

Answer (score 0):

please check if there is any frame on Dom ,if it is  there then just switch to the frame and perform the action.

If frame is not exists the go for css selector along with shycronisation

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:1**

You need to introduce **webDriverWait** here i.e visibility of element before performing any action.

**Solution:2**

You should try to switch to alert and then press on the confirm button.

> driver.switchTo().alert().accept();